# Custom model save data processor DI/Reflection only working once?

Tags: adminhtml, dependency-injection, save

I'm working on a simple FAQ widget module for a client and I seem to have run into something quite strange with the DI/Reflection cache.

My problem is with the Save controller action which uses a custom PostDataProcessor class that takes an array of ProcessorInterface[] for processing the post data which are all injected from the di.xml (adminhtml if it matters).

When I first save the question, everything works well including all processors. The next time I try to save any question I get the following error:

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor $dataProcessor ] of Nativity\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Question\Save\Interceptor class
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor does not exist
```

As I mentioned before, for one single use it's working fine... The only solution I have at the moment is clearing cashes, deleting generated code and recompiling.

Any ideas into what direction should I be focusing my debugging on?

All of the relevant code:

.../etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="processors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="data" xsi:type="object">Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor\DataProcessor</item>
                <item name="categories" xsi:type="object">Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor\CategoriesProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Nativity\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Question\FormDataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="categories" xsi:type="object">Nativity\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Question\FormDataProvider\CategoriesModifer</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

.../Controller/Adminhtml/Question/Save.php

```
<?php
namespace Nativity\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Question;

use Nativity\Faq\Api\QuestionRepositoryInterface;
use Nativity\Faq\Model\QuestionFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Nativity\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor;

class Save extends Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Nativity_Faq::question_edit';

    /**
     * @var PostDataProcessor
     */
    private $dataProcessor;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var QuestionFactory
     */
    private $questionFactory;

    /**
     * @var QuestionRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $questionRepository;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param PostDataProcessor $dataProcessor
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param QuestionFactory $questionFactory
     * @param QuestionRepositoryInterface $questionRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        PostDataProcessor $dataProcessor,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        QuestionFactory $questionFactory,
        QuestionRepositoryInterface $questionRepository
    ) {
        $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->questionFactory = $questionFactory;
        $this->questionRepository = $questionRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request */
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $data = $request->getPostValue();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try {
            $question = $this->initQuestion();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        if ($data && is_array($data)) {
            try {
                if (!isset($data['categories']))
                    $data['categories'] = [];

                $this->dataProcessor->process($question, $data);
                $this->questionRepository->save($question);
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('nt_faq_question');
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the question.'));
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $question->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (CouldNotSaveException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, $e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the question.'));
            }
            $this->dataPersistor->set('nt_faq_question', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Nativity\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function initQuestion()
    {
        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            return $this->questionRepository->get($id);
        } else {
            return $this->questionFactory->create();
        }
    }
}
```

.../UI/DataProvider/Question/PostDataProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question;

use Nativity\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface;
use Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor\ProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;

class PostDataProcessor
{
    /**
     * @var ProcessorInterface[]
     */
    private $processors;

    /**
     * @param array $processors
     *
     */
    public function __construct($processors)
    {
        $this->processors = $processors;
    }

    /**
     * @param QuestionInterface $question
     * @param array $data
     * @return QuestionInterface
     * @throws CouldNotSaveException
     */
    public function process(QuestionInterface $question, $data)
    {
        foreach ($this->processors as $processor) {
            $processor->process($question, $data);
        }
        return $question;
    }
}
```

.../Nativity/Faq/Ui/DataProvider/Question/PostDataProcessor/ProcessorInterface.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Decima Digital OU. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Nativity\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor;

use Nativity\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface;

interface ProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @param QuestionInterface $question
     * @param array $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function process(QuestionInterface $question, array $data);
}
```

.../Nativity/Faq/UI/DataProvider/Question/PostDataProcessor/DataProcesser.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Decima Digital OU. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Nativity\Faq\UI\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor;

use Nativity\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;

class DataProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Escaper
     */
    private $escaper;

    /**
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     */
    public function __construct(Escaper $escaper)
    {
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
    }

    /**
     * @param QuestionInterface $question
     * @param array $data
     * @return mixed
     * @throws CouldNotSaveException
     */
    public function process(QuestionInterface $question, array $data)
    {
        if ($this->validate($data)) {
            $questionData = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($data['question']);
            $question->setQuestion($questionData);

            $answer = $data['answer'];
            $question->setAnswer($answer);

            $storeId = $data['store_id'];
            $question->setStoreId($storeId);
        }
        return $question;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool
     * @throws CouldNotSaveException
     */
    private function validate($data)
    {
        if (isset($data['question']) && $data['question']) {
            return true;
        }
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Unable to save question'));
    }
}
```

.../Nativity/Faq/Ui/DataProvider/Question/PostDataProcessor/CategoriesProcessor.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Decima Digital OU. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Nativity\Faq\Ui\DataProvider\Question\PostDataProcessor;

use Nativity\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface;
use Nativity\Faq\Api\RelationRepositoryInterface;
use Nativity\Faq\Api\Data\RelationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Nativity\Faq\Model\RelationFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

class CategoriesProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    const FIELD_NAME = 'categories';

    /**
     * @var RelationRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $relationRepository;

    /**
     * @var RelationFactory
     */
    private $relationFactory;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * @param RelationRepositoryInterface $relationRepository
     * @param RelationFactory $relationFactory
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        RelationRepositoryInterface $relationRepository,
        RelationFactory $relationFactory,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->relationRepository = $relationRepository;
        $this->relationFactory = $relationFactory;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param QuestionInterface $question
     * @param array $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function process(QuestionInterface $question, array $data)
    {
        if ($this->validate($data)) {
            $assignedCategories = $this->getAssignedCategories($question);
            $newRelations = $this->getNewRelations($data);
            $relations = $assignedCategories + $newRelations;
            foreach ($relations as $categoryId => $relationId) {
                if (isset($assignedCategories[$categoryId]) && isset($newRelations[$categoryId])) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (isset($assignedCategories[$categoryId]) && !isset($newRelations[$categoryId])) {
                    $this->deleteRelation($relationId, $categoryId);
                    continue;
                }
                if (!isset($assignedCategories[$categoryId]) && isset($newRelations[$categoryId])) {
                    $this->addRelation($categoryId, $question->getId());
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return $question;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $relationId
     * @param int $categoryId
     * @return void
     */
    private function deleteRelation($relationId, $categoryId)
    {
        try {
            $this->relationRepository->deleteById((int)$relationId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('This question already has been removed from category ID: %1.', $categoryId)
            );
        } catch (CouldNotDeleteException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get already assigned categories array ['question_id' => 'relation_id']
     * @param QuestionInterface $question
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAssignedCategories($question)
    {
        $assignedCategories = [];
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(RelationInterface::QUESTION_ID, $question->getId())
            ->create();

        $items = $this->relationRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $assignedCategories[$item->getCategoryId()] = $item->getId();
        }
        return $assignedCategories;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    private function getNewRelations($data)
    {
        $newLinks = [];
        foreach ($data[self::FIELD_NAME] as $categoryId) {
            $newLinks[$categoryId] = '';
        }
        return $newLinks;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $categoryId
     * @param int $questionId
     * @return void
     */
    private function addRelation($categoryId, $questionId)
    {
        $relation = $this->relationFactory->create();
        $relation->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $relation->setQuestionId($questionId);
        try {
            $this->relationRepository->save($relation);
        } catch (CouldNotSaveException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Can\'t assign this question to category ID %1.', $categoryId)
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool
     */
    private function validate($data)
    {
        if (isset($data[self::FIELD_NAME]) && is_array($data[self::FIELD_NAME])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

PS - Except for the question's Save action, the rest of the system is unaffected...
PS2 - If any vital code/log for debugging this is missing let me know

**-------- SOLUTION FOUND ---------**

Well I was thrown off by the save action working once and then failing but eventually I found I had the namespace spelled wrong in a few spots "U**I**" instead of "U**i**".

My bet is this usually should result in the module failiing all together, but since I'm using a linux VBox that down in its bones still runs my pc's Windows filesystem which can be case insensitive. When modules were loaded using the file system, it was more forgiving and relayed more on the file name than the namespace. Problem is that the generated code takes that typo in and probably caches it with a different symbol because of the type. And when that symbol is in the cache but doesn't really exist in the files I got that weird exception I haven't met till this day.

Was educational learning a bit more in-depth about the DI/Reflection caching, but still wasted half a day's work on debugging because of a simple typo :o

Comment: It may help - https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/10-cache-types-how-manage-cache-magento-2.html

Comment: Clearing the cache after saving every time because of the bad dependency injection seems like an overkill. If i could just figure out whats causing the reflection cache to not save properly (seems like the issue but not sure) it's probably an easy fix, but at the moment I am clueless as to what is affecting this (my module doesn't touch anything cache related at all)

Comment: I just edited my question, after a half day of debugging I found a very simple uppercase/lowercase typo. My system's windows filesystem allowed this to work pre-cache, saving the typo in the cache and correctly in the filesystem (or the other way around). I think anyone developing on a VBox thats running on a windows desktop should be aware of this possibility. I haven't tested, but I do not believe this will happen on a Linux file system.